# Zend Pagination não exibe valores na próxima página

Tags: php, zend

Boa Tarde.

Estou utilizando (tentando) Zend Pagination (ZF 1) porém não está exibindo o resto do resultado na página seguinte.

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
 public function pesquisadocumentosAction()
    {
        if(!empty($_POST)) {
            $situacao   = $this->_getParam('situacao');
            $dtInicial  = $this->_getParam('dataInicial');
            $dtFinal    = $this->_getParam('dataFinal');
            $codGetran  = $this->_getParam('codGetran');


            if (empty($situacao) and empty($dtInicial) and empty($dtFinal) and empty($codGetran)) {

                $modDocumento = new Sisgeof_Model_DocRecebido('sisgeof');
                $filtro = $modDocumento->getAll();

                $pagina = $this->_getParam('pagina', 1);

                $paginador = Zend_Paginator::factory($filtro);
                $paginador->setItemCountPerPage(5);
                $paginador->setPageRange(9);
                $paginador->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('pagina', 1));

                Zend_Paginator::setDefaultScrollingStyle('Sliding');
                Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial('pagination.phtml');
                $this->view->assign('paginador', $paginador);

            }
```

Pagination.phtml

```
<?php if ($this->pageCount): ?>
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li>
                <?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('pagina' => $this->previous)); ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>


            <li>
            <?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>
                <?php if ($page != $this->current): ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('pagina' => $page)); ?>">
                            <span aria-hidden="true"><?php echo $page; ?></span>
                        </a>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <span aria-hidden="true"><?php echo $page; ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </li>

            <li>
                <?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('pagina' => $this->next)); ?>" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    </a>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
    </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Quando "submito" o formulário (método POST) ele cria a url ../pesquisadocumentos/page/2 mas sem resultado.

O que está havendo?

Codigo formulário:

```
<form action="<?php echo $sig_url ?>sisgeof/documento/pesquisadocumentos" method="post" name="pesquisaDocumentos" id="formular">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                Prazo do Documento:
                <select class="form-control" name="situacao">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">Maior que 6 dias</option>
                    <option value="2">Entre 3 e 5 dias</option>
                    <option value="3">Menor que 3 dias</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                Data Inicial:
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dataInicial" id="dataInicial" placeholder="__/__/____" maxlength="10">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                Data Final:
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dataFinal" id="dataFinal" placeholder="__/__/____" maxlength="10">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                Código Getran:
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codGetran" id="codGetran" maxlength="6">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-5">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Pesquisar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <!-- Div que exibe os resultados da pesquisa -->
    <?php
        if(!empty($_POST)) {
            if($this->paginador == false){
                echo $this->noResult;
                echo $this->dataInvalida;
            } else {
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <table class="table">
                <tr class="active">
                    <td><strong>Cod. Getran</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Origem</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Número do Doc.</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Ano</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Matrícula</strong></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><strong>Visualizar</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    foreach($this->paginador as $dado) :
                ?>
                    <tr class="mouseOn">
                        <td><?php echo $dado->cd_getran; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dado->origem; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dado->numero_doc; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dado->ano; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dado->cd_matricula; ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <a href="<?php echo $sig_url ?>sisgeof/documento/editadocumento?idDoc=<?php echo $dado->id_doc_recebido; ?>"
                               name="editarDocumento"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                    endforeach;
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
         } }
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-5">
            <!-- paginador -->
            <?php echo $this->paginador; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como está a configuração de rotas dessa paginação?

Comment: Não havia visto seu comentário, Desculpa. Mas acho que não tenho rotas, não vi necessáriamente isso sendo configurado em outros lugares.

Answer (score 1):

Troque a linha $paginador->setCurrentPageNumber($pagina);

por $paginador->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('pagina', 1));

Vai funcionar!

Comment: Valeu ajuda, mas não houve impacto diferente. =\

Comment: Eu criei um método de teste e outra pagina sem que haja o subimit e funciona normalmente, mas do jeito que tá não. =\

Comment: mostra como ficou o código da paginação?

Comment: Sem resultado ainda.

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite, voce quis dizer que ele exibe o mesmo resultado (mesmos registros) e qualquer pagina?

Parece estar ok seu código, mas será que não é o caso de voce tirar o seguinte trecho:

```
Zend_Paginator::setDefaultScrollingStyle('Sliding');
Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial('pagination.phtml');
```

E na sua view onde tem

```
<?php echo $this->paginador; ?>
```

Colocar

```
<?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginador, 'Sliding', 'pagination.phtml'); ?>
```

---

O que voce está passando no metodo Zend_Paginator::factory() ? Um stdClass? Será que o Zend trata isso corretamente?

Pq não tenta fazer

```
Zend_Paginator::factory((array) $filtro);
```

Uma prática bem efetiva que costumava usar com Zend 1 eh paginar a saída da query na model

```
$sql = $this->_db->select(); // Aqui segue a query normalmente

// ...

return Zend_Paginator::factory($sql);
```

Desse modo melhora até a performance, pois o banco de dados é quem faz a paginação, sacou?
;)

Espero ter ajudado, abraço.